# Is there any way to prevent a browser from requesting a file directly from IIS while still permitting it to be requested in a <script> tag?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis, webforms

I kind of doubt it because `<script>` tags just do a regular HTTP request to the script file, right? Or is there actually a way to do this? I have some ASPX scripts that I want to be loaded into `<script>` tags as they are now:

```
<script runat="server" language="VB" src="../AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldReport.aspx"></script>
```

But the problem is that if someone happens to punch in the URL of the script into their browser, they get to see the source code of the script! If this is impossible as I expect, how can I secure these scripts without breaking anything? The scripts have all sorts of weirdness going on with variables being declared in pages and referenced in the included scripts, and vice versa. So it's not a simple matter of encapsulating them into ASCX controls or VB classes/modules. Or is there some way to actually prevent direct access to these scripts from a browser while still allowing them to be loaded into a `<script>` tag?

Comment: If you press F12 in pretty much any browser you get to the "developer tools" which allow you to see the script. Why would you want to prevent anyone from seeing the JavaScript? Weirdness doesn't really count as a reason.

Comment: It's not JavaScript; it's an ASPX page containing VB code.

Answer (score 0):

URL rewrite rule can be used to prevent user access your aspx script directly.

```
 <rule name="Block browser" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="AdditionalField/AdditionalFieldReport.aspx$" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="401" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Direct access denied" statusDescription="Not allowed" />
                </rule>
```

Since HTTP_REFERRER can be faked by client side.This rule can only be used to prevent direct access.  You also need to modify and add more restriction on this rule IIS IP restriction/request filter also can help in this case.

You may need some unique identity for request filter to prevent fake request.

Comment: Wouldn't this also block access via `<script>` tags? And that regex you're using for the HTTP_REFERER, is that matching only an empty string? Not all that familiar with regexes...

Comment: Also, if this does work, how would I block access to multiple scripts? Could I add multiple `<match>` tags to the `<rule>` or would I need a separate rule for each match tag? I have several dozen scripts I want to block...

Comment: @ekolis. <Script> won't be blocked.This is just a sample because I don't know your domain. You could replace  <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^$" /> to <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="www.mydomain.com" negate="true" />. So all request that not refererred from your domain will be blocked. You could add more <condition> pattern to restrict the rule but one rule only have one <match attribute>. You could add <add input="{URL}" pattern="...." /> to restrict the access for multiple scripts.